# Performance problems in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m trying to do a SQL sentence that works fine (I think) but I have a performance problem, it takes 32 minutes to execute, and I think it can be for a poor code, can some one say me how to improve it?

This is the code:

```
SELECT distinct 
    s.nombre, l.NOMCLI cli,
    (select max(LINEAS.fecalb)  
     from LINEAS 
     where LINEAS.CODART = s.codart and LINEAS.CODCLI = l.CODCLI) fecha,
   (select MAX(proveedores.nombre) 
    from proveedores 
    where proveedores.codpro = s.codpro) proveedor,
(SELECT MAX(LINEAS.CODREP) FROM LINEAS WHERE LINEAS.CODART=S.codart) representante
 FROM stock AS S  INNER JOIN LINEAS as l ON S.codart=l.CODART
  WHERE
 s.codart in(select LINEAS.CODART from lineas inner join stock on
  LINEAS.CODART=stock.codart where datediff("d",lineas.fecalb,getdate())<365 and stock.stoexi>0 group by LINEAS.CODART having COUNT(lineas.CODART)<=2
 )and
  (S.codart IN(
 SELECT ST.CODART FROM STOCK AS ST WHERE ST.codart NOT IN
 (SELECT LINEAS.CODART FROM LINEAS WHERE 
DATEDIFF("d",lineas.fecalb,getdate())<=60) AND ST.stoexi>0) 
OR
s.codart IN
(SELECT LINEAS.CODART FROM LINEAS WHERE 
DATEDIFF("d",lineas.fecalb,getdate())<182 GROUP BY LINEAS.CODART
HAVING COUNT(LINEAS.CODART)<=2 AND (s.stoexi>0))
OR
S.codart IN
(SELECT LINEAS.CODART FROM LINEAS where  DATEDIFF("d",lineas.fecalb,getdate())<=182
GROUP BY LINEAS.CODART HAVING SUM(LINEAS.UNIDAD)<S.stoexi))

order by s.nombre,l.NOMCLI desc ;
```

First I have more or less the same sentence without the first condition

```
 s.codart in (select LINEAS.CODART 
              from lineas 
              inner join stock on LINEAS.CODART = stock.codart 
              where datediff("d", lineas.fecalb, getdate()) < 365 
                and stock.stoexi > 0 
              group by LINEAS.CODART 
              having COUNT(lineas.CODART) <= 2) and
```

Works fine it only takes a 18 seconds.

the líneas table have 600000 rows and stock 53000

Comment: The second query's runtime is aready absurd. Have a look at the execution plan of the query and it should be pretty obvious why it's taking so long - I'd assume wrong indexing, and your use of `datediff`, but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: even 18 seconds for the whole thing would be too long imho...this query is horrible to read and understand.

Comment: At least part of the performance issue is likely the non-sargable expressions in the `WHERE` clause.  Avoid applying functions to columns because that prevents using indexes efficiently,  Instead, refactor such that the column is compared directly.  Try changing `datediff("d",lineas.fecalb,getdate())<365` to `lineas.fecalb >= DATEADD(day, -365, getdate())` and use the same pattern for the other `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: @DanGuzman you mean `DATEADD(DAY,-365, GETDATE())` don't you?

Comment: They are called queries not sentences.

Comment: THANKS for your answers, i´m going to try your suggestions and i will coment again.

I´m new in the world of the sql, can someone say me where to find about the execution plan?

Comment: INCREDIBLE with your tips the time down to 35 seconds. I need to learn much more about SQL.
Any one knows a good book of Transact-SQL(if it can be in spanish better) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the condition you are calculating the `datediff` for each record. The database won't be able to use an index for the field, as the field isn't compared to a specific value. Instead you should calculate the point in time to compare the field to.

Instead of:

```
DATEDIFF("d",lineas.fecalb,getdate())<182
```

try:

```
lineas.fecalb >= dateadd("d", -182, getdate())
```

---

Your use of `distinct` means that you actually will run those subqueries more times than you need, just to discard the duplicates. You should try to first filter out the records that you want the result for, then you can run subqueries on that.

Answer (score 0):

In general correlated subqueries run one row at a time and are performance hogs. You should virtually never use them in the select portion of the query.

You also have a bunch of OR conditions, those too are slow and usually using a UNION or UNION ALL will be faster. Short example:
This can be replaced

```
select myfield, someotherfield, yetanotherfield 
from  mytable 
where myfield = 1 or (myfield = 2 and someotherfield like 'abc%')
```

with this (I used UNion all because these are mutually exclusive)

```
select myfield, someotherfield, yetanotherfield 
from  mytable 
where myfield = 1 
Union ALL
select myfield, someotherfield, yetanotherfield 
from  mytable 
where myfield = 2 and someotherfield like 'abc%'
```

The EXISTS clause is often faster than using IN.

You need to consider the sargability of all where clauses and if they can be rewritten to use indexes.

Comment: Thanks for responding, i think you are right saying many conditions slows the query, but i don´t see how can i replace the OR condition with UNION. From what i have seen UNION is used to join the result of 2 or more queries and what i need is to filter. If you can explain me how can i do it i would appreciate